# How do I add my getAttribute propiety to my localStorage

Tags: javascript, session-storage, getattribute

I am trying to create a cart, below are the steps I need to follow:
step 1: find a way to move item information such as price and description from the item page to the purchase page by a click of a button.`enter code here`
step 2: find a way to extract the price from the item information and add them together.
step 3: find a way to add the prices together then remove taxes from it?

so for step 1: I am using a getAttribute property to identify the information I want to move over to the purchase page, I think the getAttribute property is the best way I can extract all the prices on the purchase page once moved over from the items page, therefore I need to find a way to localStorage a getAttribute property.

I have so far created test HTML and js code to try to move the information from one HTML page to the other.

```js
function ready() {
var First = document.getElementById('test');

First.getAttribute("data-price");
First.getAttribute("data-name");
First.getAttribute("data-description");
sessionStorage.data-price;
};


alert(sessionStorage.setItem("data-price",First))

function show(){

 sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.setItem("data-price",First))
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    show();
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="store.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to get values of the `data-` attributes.

```
function ready() {
    var First = document.getElementById("test");

    const price = First.dataset.price;
    const name = First.dataset.name;
    const description = First.dataset.description;

    sessionStorage.setItem("price", price);
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
    sessionStorage.setItem("description", description);
}

function show() {
    const price = sessionStorage.getItem('price');
    alert(price);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be done with the following:

```
function ready() {
    var First = document.getElementById('test');
    First.getAttribute("data-price");
    First.getAttribute("data-name");
    First.getAttribute("data-description");
    localStorage.setItem("data-price", JSON.stringify(First));
};

function show() {
    alert(localStorage.getItem("data-price"));
}
```